# exactly one box contains exactly one defective component

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

There are two boxes, each containing two components. Each component is defective with probability 1/4, independent of all other components. The probability that exactly one box contains exactly one defective component equals?

Comment: **Hint:** This happens if (and only if) exactly one or exactly three of the four components are defective.

Comment: that's a good point, I couldn't understand why it was more than the chance of 1 fault only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P(1 faulty in box) = C(2,1) (1/4)(3/4) = 3 / 8

the chances of a box having other than 1 fault is 5/8

The P(1 exactly one fault in exactly one box) = C(2,1)(3/8)(5/8) = 15/32

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: exactly one is defective among four:

$ p_1 = {4 \choose 1} \left(\frac 1 4 \right) \left(\frac 3 4 \right)^3 = \frac {27} {64} $.

Case 2: any one defective in any one box and both defective in another box:

$ p_2 = {2 \choose 1} {2 \choose 1} \left(\frac 1 4\right) \left(\frac 3 4\right) \left(\frac 1 4\right)^2 = \frac 3 {64} $.

Total probability $ = p_1 + p_2 = \frac {30} {64} = \frac {15} {32} $ .